# Blocking event loop when a particular function is running

Tags: node.js

I'm assuming the answer to this is really simple.

I *want* to block the nodejs event loop whenever a particular function is running.  The function itself might call some async things it waits on, but I don't want anything else to happen while this function is doing its thing.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to block the event loop in node.js is to make the code synchronous:

```
while (true) {
  // this will block the event loop
}
```

Recursion is also synchronous

```
  function rec() {
    rec();
  }

  // This one exists with RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Using any synchronous functions like:

```
fs.readFileSync()
fs.writeFileSync()

// any sync functions will do
```

If you intend to create a timeout, that blocks everything just create a for loop to a billion and it will stop for a while.

> Your request seems unnatural, maybe it is not node.js that you need. Usually, people in node are trying to make everything asynchronous.

Comment: "Your request seems unnatural, maybe it is not node.js that you need. Usually, people in node are trying to make everything asynchronous."  Point taken.  Sometimes you might want synchonous for whatever reason for something and I was curious what a good approach is... but I am now also curious what readFileSync etc do under the hood.